# Lebesgue measure on countable union

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Given the Borel set $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[n,n+1/n]$ how do I find its Lebesgue measure?

My attempt: Given $\lambda$ we have that 
\begin{align*}
\lambda(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[n,n+1/n])&=\lambda([1,2]\cup[2,2+1/4])+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\lambda([n,n+1/n]) &&\text{Additive}\\
&=\lambda([1,2+1/2]) +\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}&&\\
&=1+1/2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}&&\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

The harmonic series diverges, hence $\lambda(A)=+\infty$.

Is this true? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a typo, you want $1/2$ instead of $1/4$. Otherwise it is true. Which step worries you?

Comment: Yes it is true, and the last quantity is equal to $+\infty$, so $\lambda(A)=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I consider this closed then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you miscalculated the measure, although the mistake is not essential in terms of the result, which is simply $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$.

Comment: I've updated using the comments, but thank you for the observation. +1